# Anyway to salvage this code snippet to avoid memory bottlenecks?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, out-of-memory

This snippet below was obtained from https://github.com/suanrong/SDNE in `/utils/utils.py`.

The issue I am having is this `get_precisionK` function calls the `getSimilarity` function which computes the product of a NxM matrix and its transpose. The product is symmetric and is NxN, so we could decrease memory usage by almost half. But the bigger issue here is N is on the order of `10**5`. In the particular problem I am working with, N is about 600k.

A 600k x 600k matrix of doubles requires like 3TB of memory, something that I do not have. So the code is crashing (because of memory limitations) when trying to compute the `np.dot`. I am trying to restructure the code without exceeding memory limitations. But the way the function uses the product makes it a little difficult.

The only thing that I could come up with is feeding in a subset of the rows of the `embedding` matrix to the `getSimilarity` function, and compute the product, then sort this and write this to a file (EDIT: Actually instead of sorting and writing to file, I think I would just write the values to the file, and sort it later on). So we'd end up having multiple files with sorted indices, we'd have to sync all the files together into one big giant file somehow. The syncing part is another challenge I think.

The `for` loop loops in descending order. I would need to then read in consecutive small portions (whatever memory allows) of the aforementioned giant file, and do the operations.

This sounds quite complicated and I wanted to see if any others have better ideas.

```
def getSimilarity(result):
    print "getting similarity..."
    return np.dot(result, result.T)

****Note that embedding is NxM mumpy array where N is very large, ~ O(10^5) ****
def check_reconstruction(embedding, graph_data, check_index):
    def get_precisionK(embedding, data, max_index):
        print "get precisionK..."
        similarity = getSimilarity(embedding).reshape(-1)
        sortedInd = np.argsort(similarity)
        cur = 0
        count = 0
        precisionK = []
        sortedInd = sortedInd[::-1]
        for ind in sortedInd:
            x = ind / data.N
            y = ind % data.N
            count += 1
            if (data.adj_matrix[x].toarray()[0][y] == 1 or x == y):
                cur += 1 
            precisionK.append(1.0 * cur / count)
            if count > max_index:
                break
        return precisionK

    precisionK = get_precisionK(embedding, graph_data, np.max(check_index))
    ret = []
    for index in check_index:
        print "precisonK[%d] %.2f" % (index, precisionK[index - 1])
        ret.append(precisionK[index - 1])
    return ret
```